# Getting ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean while persisting Map<String, Boolean> to database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using Spring MVC and trying to save a basic questionnaire with yes/no (true/false) answers to a `Map<String, Boolean>`, where the String key is "Q1", "Q2" respectively.

On the controller side, it binds properly, setting the respective input values to the Map, but when the entity object is passed to the service to save, a ClassCastException is thrown complaining that it cannot be saved. The database (postgres) type is boolean.

Exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.BooleanTypeDescriptor.unwrap(BooleanTypeDescriptor.java:19) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BooleanTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BooleanTypeDescriptor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:903) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.doUpdateRows(BasicCollectionPersister.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.updateRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1728) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public class Questionnaire {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String[] SHORT_QUESTIONS = {"q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "q6", "q7"};

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="question")
    @Column(name="answer")
    private Map<String, Boolean> shortForm = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // constructor, setters and getters here
}
```

Controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/questionnaire/save/{id}")
public String save(@ModelAttribute @Valid Questionnaire questionnaire, BindingResult binder, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, Model model) {
    if (binder.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("messageDanger", messages.getMessage("general.save.failed", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
        return "questionnaire/full";
    }

    // these all bind properly and return true or false accordingly
    log.debug("q1: " + questionnaire.getShortForm().get("q1"));
    log.debug("q2: " + questionnaire.getShortForm().get("q2"));
    log.debug("q3: " + questionnaire.getShortForm().get("q3"));
    log.debug("q4: " + questionnaire.getShortForm().get("q4"));
    log.debug("q5: " + questionnaire.getShortForm().get("q5"));
    log.debug("q6: " + questionnaire.getShortForm().get("q6"));

    // Exception occurs here during .save()
    questionnaireSvc.save(questionnaire);

    redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("message", messages.getMessage("general.save.success", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
    return "redirect:/questionnaire/full/" + questionnaire.getId();
}
```

HTML (Thymeleaf)

```
<tr th:each="question : ${T(app.model.Questionnaire).SHORT_QUESTIONS}">
    <td headers="question-col" th:utext="#{questionnaire.short.__${question}__}"></td>
    <td headers="applicant-col">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{shortForm[__${question}__]}" class="custom-control-input" required value="false" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" th:text="#{general.no}" th:for="${#ids.prev('shortForm__${question}__')}"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" th:field="*{shortForm[__${question}__]}" class="custom-control-input" required value="true" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" th:text="#{general.yes}" th:for="${#ids.prev('shortForm__${question}__')}"></label>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: What database type is answer

Comment: Could you also provide generated DDL of your database?

Comment: Sorry, my database (postgres) type is boolean

Comment: Am not sure how are you storing Java Map into postgres Database